# $X=\operatorname{Proj} k[x_0,x_1]$. $V_1=\Gamma(X,O_X(1))$.$f:X\to\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ structural map. $f^\star(V_1)=O_{X,x_0}\oplus O_{X,x_1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is related to Ueno's Algebraic Geometry 2, Chpt 5, Sec 3, (b) Segre morphism.

$X= \operatorname{Proj}(k[x_0,x_1])$. Let $f:X\to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ be structural morphism. Let $V_1=\Gamma(X,O_X(1))=f_\star(O_X(1))$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $f^\star(V_1)=O_{X,x_0}\oplus O_{X,x_1}$? $V_1$ is really 2 dimensional vector space. So $V_1=k^2$. Now $f^\star(V_1)=f^\star(k\oplus k)=f^\star(k)\oplus f^\star(k)$. It suffices to consider $f^\star(k)$. $f^\star(k)=f^{-1}(k)\otimes_{f^{-1}(k)}O_X$. Restrict to affine level, it is obvious that $f^\star(k)|_{x_0\neq 0}=k[\frac{x_1}{x_0}]$. Then glue to give $O_X$. What is the meaning of notation $O_{X,x_0}$? $x_0=0$ or $x_0\neq 0$? My guess is that this is local ring. The other interpretation is that $x_0$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space, $p\in X$, and $F$ is a sheaf then $F_p$ refers to the stalk of $F$ at $p$. In your case $X$ is a scheme, so it has a structure sheaf, denoted by $O_X$, so $O_{X,x_0}$ would then refer to the stalk of the structure sheaf over $X$ at the point $x_0$. Let me know if I should delete my comment if I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki My major concern is that why I get $f^\star f_\star(O_X(1))=O_{X,x_0}\oplus O_{X,x_1}$ instead of $O_X\oplus O_X$.

Comment: You are right. Maybe the notation means something like "$O_X\langle x_0\rangle \oplus O_X \langle x_1\rangle $" in the sense that $f^*(V_1)$ is isomorphic to $O_X\oplus O_X$ and locally generated by $x_0$ and $x_1$ seen as global section of $O_X(1)$.